laravel and websocket - WebSocket connection failed
I'm using laravel, websocket and laravel-echo to build simple chat app it works fine on localhost when using ws://127.0.0.1:6000
but when upload app on the host and try tor run through wss://my-domain.com
i got
WebSocket connection to 'wss://shueur-app.shueur.com/app/865dc1ca593866642712? 
protocol=7&client=js&version=8.4.0-rc2&flash=false' failed: 

and here is my config
.env file
PUSHER_APP_ID=1870264
PUSHER_APP_HOST="my-domain.com"
PUSHER_APP_KEY=key
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=secret
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1
PUSHER_APP_PORT=443
VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
VITE_PUSHER_HOST="${PUSHER_APP_HOST}"
VITE_PUSHER_PORT="${PUSHER_APP_PORT}"
VITE_PUSHER_SCHEME="https"
VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"

LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_CERT="/home/shueurco/ssl/certs/shueur_app_shueur_com_d089e_8225b_1735046002_86197ef80e37f38293f9f3f8b4b5167c.crt"
LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_PK="/home/shueurco/ssl/keys/d089e_8225b_a195c551e1e59eb253da9d44c2872131.key"

braodcast.php
'pusher' => [
        'driver' => 'pusher',
        'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
        'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
            'encrypted' => true,
            'useTLS' => true,
             'host' => env('PUSHER_APP_HOST'),
             'port' => env('PUSHER_APP_PORT'),
            'scheme' => 'https',
            'curl_options' => [
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0
            ]
        ],

websockets.php
'dashboard' => [
    'port' => env('LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_PORT', 443),
],

app.js
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';
import Pusher from 'pusher-js';

window.Pusher = Pusher;

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER || 'mt1',
    wsHost: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_HOST ? import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_HOST :`ws-${import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}.pusher.com`,
    wsPort: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_PORT ?? 80,
    wssPort: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_PORT ?? 443,
    forceTLS: (import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_SCHEME ?? 'https') === 'https',
    enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
    encrypted: (import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_SCHEME ?? 'https') === 'https',
      auth: {
         headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token'),
       }
     }
  });


have you start it? php artisan websockets:serve

Thank you for your response. I contacted customer service and found that my hosting plan doesn’t support WebSocket, so I upgraded to a VPS.
Now it works perfectly.
